# Eslint not detecting tailwind.config

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, tailwind-css

Im having problems setting up tailwind on my React project. I am using eslint, and I wanted to add tailwind and asked me to add it as a project, but then it says it is not correct: Error on tailwind.config.js and postcss.config.js:

Tailwind.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {}
  },
  plugins: []
};
```

Here is my eslint config:

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "extends": [
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "standard-with-typescript",
    "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:react-hooks/recommended",
    "plugin:tailwindcss/recommended",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "prettier"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "overrides": [],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": { "jsx": true },
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "project": "frontend/tsconfig.json",
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint", "react-hooks", "prettier", "tailwindcss"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error",
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".tsx"] }],
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": "off"
  }
}
```

Here is my postcss.config.js

```
{
  "content": ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  "theme": {
    "extend": {}
  },
  "plugins": {
    "tailwindcss": {},
    "autoprefixer": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: change your **tailwind.config.js** :  `module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}`

Comment: I have it already like that, and is still throwing me that error

Comment: add your `postcss.config.js` as well

Comment: I added it to the issue

Comment: Please replace the screenshots of your configuration files with their text equivalents. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Delete `"content": ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  "theme": {
    "extend": {}` from **postcss.config.js**